# Problem in partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu and I am currently running Windows 10 but I don't want to remove my Windows 10 and when I am  installing  Ubuntu I am having problem during installation in my hard disk as I want to make my system dual boot. I am having 10 GB of unallocated space on my system but it is not showing during installation.

Please help as it is important for me to install Ubuntu because of my work

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are trying to install?

Comment: What brand/model system? Is Windows 10 UEFI, or upgrade from Windows 7 and probably BIOS/MBR?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

My my system is HP 240 G3 notebook
I updated my Windows from 8. 1 to 10 induction I am not getting about bios and uefi
Ubuntu version is 18. 04. 1